# Paste one image on another with out distorting the source image

Tags: java, image

I need to crop 3X3 pixcel portions from an image and paste the croped portions in another image. I used the drawImage method to paste the portions. But while doing this the colour of the source image is getting changed and some pixcels are distorted.

```
      int t1=0,t2=0;
      targetFile=ImageIO.read(new File("Sky.png"));

      for(int i=0;i<=6;i+=3){
      for(int j=0;j<=6;j+=3){
           Graphics g=targetFile.getGraphics();
          BufferedImage dest=source.getSubimage(i, j, 3, 3);
           g.drawImage(dest, t1,t2, Color.BLUE,null);
           t1+=5;
          t2+=5;
          g.dispose();
     }
      }

         File f2=new File("myimg1.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(targetFile, "jpg", f2);
```

Comment: A bit unclear what the question is. A wild guess: Write the output image as a `"png"` as well. Does the problem still happen? If not, the problem is not in the algorithm, but in the JPG compression (which is rather high in `ImageIO`, by default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're saving the file as a JPG. JPG files are stored using a lossy compression algorithm, causing slight graphical artifacts in order to save space, hence the perceived distortion.

Try saving it as a lossless format instead, such as PNG.

Comment: Yes the problem solved.I changed the extension to png.